# Meaning of /dev/ashmem (deleted) records in process maps

Tags: android, linux-kernel, ram, ashmem

I'm wondering what is the meaning of next records in `/proc/<pid>/maps`:

```
...
cdbc2000-cdbc6000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 1290888                            /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted)
cdbc6000-cdbcf000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 1290887                            /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted)
cdbcf000-cdbdf000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 1290886                            /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted)
...
```

Especially what does `(deleted)` mean? Is this memory range is held by something within process and should be released later or these records are just markers and there is no associated physical memory ? I.e. may plain call to `mmap()` return mapping that intersects such ranges?

P.S. range names may differ slightly but they always contain `/dev/ashmem ... (deleted)`.

Comment: Ashmem (Anonymous shared memory) See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970858/what-special-powers-does-ashmem-have and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837507/writing-to-ashmem-why-does-android-free-ashmem for additional information.

Comment: @ditkin the second link is really helpful. Many thanks!